# Create filename with metadata

Tags: python, python-3.x, markdown

If it possible to create md file with some atributes and save it to .md format on python?
So i have atributes:

```
year="2018"
month="12"
```

and i need save it, for example, to 2018_12_metadata.md file with needful atributes. Here's how md file should look like

```
{
  "year": "2018",
  "month": "12"
}
```

So i have some code, but i could find how save it to md format with needful atributes:

```
year="2018"
month="12"
path_folder="C:\\Users\" 
MD_output = path_folder + year +'-'+ month +'_metadata.md'
md_file - what should be here?
md_file.write(MD_output)
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Make a dictionary

```
metadata = {
  "year": "2018",
  "month": "12"
}
```

Setup your filepath

```
path_folder="C:\\Users\\" 
md_file = "{}\\{year}_{month}_metadata.md".format(path_folder, *metadata)
```

Open a file and write to it

```
with open(md_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write("foobar")
```

Or if all you wanted to do is write a dictionary to a file, load it as JSON

```
import json
with open(md_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(metadata, f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Dears, here is solution that i found:

```
result = {'year': '2018',
          'month': '12'}
file_name="Check"
with open(os.path.join(path_folder, '{}.md'.format(file_name)), mode='w') as md_file:
    json.dump(result, md_file, indent=2)
```

Thanks all for help.